# Django adding foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I am working on a student assignment submission project, I have made the submission model, which has assignment as foreign key to question, student as a foreign key to the profile.
I am working on some way where teacher can select the list of students who have submitted the assignment and assign marks to them, I tried the following way, but its form is not getting validated stating that "select a valid choice"

Submission model

```
class Submission(models.Model):
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(Assignment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='assignment')
    student = models.ForeignKey(StudentProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='student')
    answer = models.URLField()
    time_submitted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    marks_obtained = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

MarkUpdateForm

```
class MarksUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Submission
        fields = ['student', 'marks_obtained']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.assignment_id = kwargs.pop('assignment_id', None)
        super(MarksUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['student'].queryset = Submission.objects.filter(assignment__id=self.assignment_id).values_list(
            'student__user__username', flat=True)
```

My view

```
            form = MarksUpdateForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                row = Submission.objects.get(id=assignmentId,
                                             student__user__username=form.cleaned_data['student'])
                row.marks_obtained = form.cleaned_data['marks_obtained']
                row.save()
                messages.success(request,
                                 message="Marks Updated Successfully")
            else:
                print(form.errors)
```

I tried updating my marksupdateform by overriding label_from_instance and creating custom form instead of model form, but didnt solve the error of "select a valid choice"
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to get the student queryset by filtering the `Submission` model from the `StudentProfile` model

```
self.fields['student'].queryset = StudentProfile.objects.filter(
    submission__assignment__id=self.assignment_id
)
```

To get the username's as the display text on the select dropdown, you can update the `StudentProfile` model as such:

```
class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Answer (score 1):

`Submission.student` is a `ForeignKey` to the `StudentProfile` model, therefore the queryset used for `MarksUpdateForm.student` should be a `StudentProfile` queryset

```
self.fields['student'].queryset = StudentProfile.objects.filter(
    submission__assignment_id=self.assignment_id
)
```

Comment: Yes, I understood the mistake there. but I do not have a submission as a field in studentprofile model, how can i reference to student in that case.